# Remove Special Characters in KQL

Tags: kql

How can I remove [" and "] in KQL from the below column values?

```
["xyz@test.com"]  
["abc@test.com"]  
["123@test.com"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you would also like to remove the double quotes.

```
datatable(col:string)
[
     '["xyz@test.com"]'  
    ,'["abc@test.com"]' 
    ,'["123@test.com"]'
]
| extend option_1 = trim(@'^\["|"]$', col)          // Trim opening [" and closing "]
| extend option_2 = trim(@'[[\]"]+', col)           // Trim sequences of the characters [, ] and "
| extend option_3 = extract(@'^\["(.*)"]$', 1, col) // Extract the expression between the opening [" and closing "]
| extend option_4 = tostring(todynamic(col)[0])     // Convert to json (resulting in json array) and retrieve the 1st element
```

| col | option_1 | option_2 | option_3 | option_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["xyz@test.com"] | xyz@test.com | xyz@test.com | xyz@test.com | xyz@test.com |
| ["abc@test.com"] | abc@test.com | abc@test.com | abc@test.com | abc@test.com |
| ["123@test.com"] | 123@test.com | 123@test.com | 123@test.com | 123@test.com |

Fiddle