# How to parse the string tye column using kql query

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have the KQL Query that gets the function app logs in Azure Log Analytics Workspace.

The Column Values are like `["[{\"ServiceNamd\":\"user-service\",\""]`.

This column values are fetched from the other column using split method.

I'm unable to remove special characters from the string. My requirement is to print the column values like `Service Name:user-service`

```
FunctionAppLogs
| Where Function Name contains "HealthCheckApI"
| extend ServiceName = trim(@'[["\"]+', Mesage)
```

I tried the solutions given in SO [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72414184) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72884055) but unable to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the below KQL query and got the expected result

```
Functions
| extend abc = replace_string(Message, '\"', "")
| extend ServiceName = split(split(abc, '{')[1], ",")[0]
| project ServiceName
```

**`Output:`**

[image]